# How to load data from AWS S3 using Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I am to use Pig Latin to retrieve CSV files that are saved and organised according to date. I want to automate this process and get yesterday's data.

Below is the code:

```
tempdate = CurrentTime();
-- P1D = period of 1 day in ISO format
yesterday = foreach tempdate generate SubtractDuration(tempdate,P1D);

$date = ToString(yesterday, "YYYY-MM-dd"); 

data = load 's3://folder/folder/$date' as(a: tuple()) ;
dump data;
```

But I keep getting this error:

**[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext - Encountered "" at line 1, column 5.**

And if I try to simply load data like so:

```
A = LOAD 's3://folder/folder/date/file.csv' as (line: chararray);
dump A;
```

I get this error:

**[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext - Encountered " "=" "= "" at line 1, column 1.**

How do you avoid getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your first script is completely against how Pig script should be implemented. You can't specify variables inside scripts as you can for example in Python. You can however pass eg. date by parameter by appending `-param date="2015-03-25"` to your Pig command. If you want the parameter to be dynamic you can do this.

```
-param date=`date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

The second script works for me when I run it.

Comment: What if I want to automate the whole process without supplying parameters? So instead of supplying parameters I would like to have this script to be run in batch mode. How would you achieve this using Pig?

Comment: I don't really understand what you could not automate above parameters as they are relative?